# C# rtmp-player library

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, streaming, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm creating a C# application and I need it to play rtmp live streams. I don't have to create an ultimate tool like VLC player, because playing streams isn't main purpose of my app. The only thing about RTMP, I have to make, is just playing stream in WPF window. The problem is, I don't know, how to do it.

I've found several RTMP libraries (such as Broccoli), but as far as I know, they can only record video in flv files, but can't play it.

I've also tryed to use FFplay in my project and it works fine, but this tool playes stream in it's self window and I have no idea how to put it into my WPF form (it's necessarily).

The only variant which really works is putting a Flash player into my WPF window via AxShockwaveFlash and WindowsFormsHost objects, but it's quite resource-intensive (especially creaing and disposing operations), so I don't think this is the best choice.

What can you advice me?